# When using float, margin gets disregarded

Tags: html, css, e-commerce

I am trying to create a navigation bar for my website. Beside the cart option, I would like to incorparate a shopping cart image. I am trying to use float:right; and margin to be able to position this element. For some reason, the margin is disregarded and doesn't work. I have looked over countless questions regarding this topic, but none of the answers have been relevant to my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Once again, I understand their are many questions regarding my problem, but none of them have resulted in a fix. I have also tried padding, but that didn't work either. Thanks in advance for any help. It is greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```css
.cart {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 975px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Login/Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <img src="shoppingcart.png" class="cart" height=25 width=25>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `float:right`, it is logically to use `margin-right` property because `float: right` will push the item to the most right and if you want to set some margin between the element and the most right boundary you have to use the `margin-right`.

The opposite way won't work because you are setting the element to float right, but at the same time you are setting its left margin which will be overriden by the float property.

Also setting the left margin is a hard-coded solution, i.e. you don't know how big margin is required on different screen size. But instead it is most probably that you know how big the margin should be from the right side.

Please take a look at the snippet below.

```css
.cart {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login/Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
  </ul>

  </nav>

  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/28468-200.png" class="cart" height=25 width=25>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. You fixed my problem. Thank you very much. I will accept the answer now!

Comment: Glad to help you